# How to make executable file independent of Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have one library, one txt file for import some things with it and one output file to show the result. Only have one java file without any interface. With eclipse all is running well - I am writing into the input file and then it shows the result into the output file. Now I want to make this all independent program (without need to run with eclipse). 
How to make it?

Comment: Things to google: command line, java command

Answer (score 1):

An easier way is to make a runnable JAR file.

Go into eclipse choose file > export > runnable JAR.
It will then ask you to choose a class for a launch configuration. Choose the class that has the main method for the desired program. After that you will have a file that will run (like a .exe but just a different format).

If can't get it to work with your input and output files, thats because eclipse has this weird thing that sometimes occurs regarding the location of external sources when exporting to JAR. To fix it, just put the files instead of the src (source) folder, one folder up in the directory. For example, if this is your current directory: C:\workspace\myprogram\src put it in C:\workspace\myprogram

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

The only thing that eclipse is is a software that facilitates progtammi g. But what find the programs is the jvm-java virtual machine. To get to the point eclipse does have a option to convert it to a .jar file which the extension a java program uses to be "independent" from eclipse and open up by double clicking. The way you do this is you right click on the class you want to make independent and I think there should an option that says export to .jar and that should do the trick! Hope this was helpful